# Argparse: how to handle variable number of arguments (nargs='*')

Tags: python, argparse

I thought that `nargs='*'` was enough to handle a variable number of arguments. Apparently it's not, and I don't understand the cause of this error.

The code:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('pos')
p.add_argument('foo')
p.add_argument('--spam', default=24, type=int, dest='spam')
p.add_argument('vars', nargs='*')

p.parse_args('1 2 --spam 8 8 9'.split())
```

I think the resulting namespace should be `Namespace(pos='1', foo='2', spam='8', vars=['8', '9'])`. Instead, argparse gives this error:

```
usage: prog.py [-h] [--spam SPAM] pos foo [vars [vars ...]]
error: unrecognized arguments: 9 8
```

Basically, argparse doesn't know where to put those additional arguments... Why is that?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The relevant Python bug is [Issue 15112](http://bugs.python.org/issue15112).

> `argparse: nargs='*'` positional argument doesn't accept any items if preceded by an option and another positional

When argparse parses `['1', '2', '--spam', '8', '8', '9']` it first tries to match `['1','2']` with as many of the positional arguments as possible.  With your arguments the pattern matching string is `AAA*`: 1 argument each for `pos` and `foo`, and zero arguments for `vars` (remember `*` means ZERO_OR_MORE).

`['--spam','8']` are handled by your `--spam` argument.  Since `vars` has already been set to `[]`, there is nothing left to handle `['8','9']`.

The programming change to `argparse` checks for the case where `0` argument strings is satisfying the pattern, but there are still `optionals` to be parsed.  It then defers the handling of that `*` argument.

You might be able to get around this by first parsing the input with [`parse_known_args`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args), and then handling the `remainder` with another call to [`parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args).

To have complete freedom in interspersing optionals among positionals, in [issue 14191](http://bugs.python.org/issue14191), I propose using `parse_known_args` with just the `optionals`, followed by a `parse_args` that only knows about the positionals.  The `parse_intermixed_args` function that I posted there could be implemented in an `ArgumentParser` subclass, without modifying the `argparse.py` code itself.

---

Here's a way of handling subparsers.  I've taken the [`parse_known_intermixed_args`](http://bugs.python.org/file30422/intermixed.patch) function, simplified it for presentation sake, and then made it the `parse_known_args` function of a Parser subclass.  I had to take an extra step to avoid recursion.

Finally I changed the `_parser_class` of the subparsers Action, so each subparser uses this alternative `parse_known_args`.  An alternative would be to subclass `_SubParsersAction`, possibly modifying its `__call__`.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def parse_known_intermixed_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
    # self - argparse parser
    # simplified from http://bugs.python.org/file30204/test_intermixed.py
    parsefn = super(SubParser, self).parse_known_args # avoid recursion

    positionals = self._get_positional_actions()
    for action in positionals:
        # deactivate positionals
        action.save_nargs = action.nargs
        action.nargs = 0

    namespace, remaining_args = parsefn(args, namespace)
    for action in positionals:
        # remove the empty positional values from namespace
        if hasattr(namespace, action.dest):
            delattr(namespace, action.dest)
    for action in positionals:
        action.nargs = action.save_nargs
    # parse positionals
    namespace, extras = parsefn(remaining_args, namespace)
    return namespace, extras

class SubParser(ArgumentParser):
    parse_known_args = parse_known_intermixed_args

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo')
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
sp._parser_class = SubParser # use different parser class for subparsers
spp1 = sp.add_parser('cmd1')
spp1.add_argument('-x')
spp1.add_argument('bar')
spp1.add_argument('vars',nargs='*')

print parser.parse_args('foo cmd1 bar -x one 8 9'.split())
# Namespace(bar='bar', cmd='cmd1', foo='foo', vars=['8', '9'], x='one')
```

Comment: Oh this is good news. So are you saying that if I take the two functions you added in http://bugs.python.org/file30422/intermixed.patch and I implement in my own subclass I'll be able to get around the problem? What about the `_get_values()` function, is the two-lines change to it strictly necessary? I find it difficult to understand how `SUPPRESS` is used.

Comment: Oh no, bad news just arrived. I read that this is incompatible with subparsers, a feature I absolutely need. Is that temporary or just impossible to realize? Instinctively I'd say that it should be possible to do, because the subparser is specified as second argument, then the parsing happens normally. Am I wrong?

Comment: I tried 2 different ways of temporarily disabling the `positional` arguments.  The first was `nargs=0`.  The second was `nargs=SUPPRESS`.  I would use the first if implementing my own subclass.  `SUPPRESS` has some advantages but requires deeper changes to `argparse.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/file30204/test_intermixed.py is a better example of patching your own parser.

Comment: My `parse_intermixed_arg` function does object if there is a subparser argument (`argparse.PARSER`).  I have added some code that gets around that constraint, by using the `intermixed` approach only in the subparsers.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do as you suggest.

Comment: Could do with an update now that issue14191 is fixed

Answer (score 110):

For anyone who doesn't know what is `nargs`:

`nargs` stands for `Number Of Arguments`

- `3`: 3 values, can be any number you want
- `?`: a single value, which can be optional
- `*`: a flexible number of values, which will be gathered into a list
- `+`: like *, but requiring at least one value
- `argparse.REMAINDER`: all the values that are remaining in the command
  line

> Example:

**Python**

```
import argparse

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
my_parser.add_argument('--input', action='store', type=int, nargs=3)

args = my_parser.parse_args()

print(args.input)
```

**Console**

```
$ python nargs_example.py --input 42
usage: nargs_example.py [-h] [--input INPUT INPUT INPUT]
nargs_example.py: error: argument --input: expected 3 arguments

$ python nargs_example.py --input 42 42 42
[42, 42, 42]
```

[See more](https://realpython.com/command-line-interfaces-python-argparse/)

Answer (score 16):

Simple solution: Specify the `--spam` flag before specifying `pos` and `foo`:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('pos')
p.add_argument('foo')
p.add_argument('--spam', default=24, type=int, dest='spam')
p.add_argument('vars', nargs='*')

p.parse_args('--spam 8 1 2 8 9'.split())
```

The same works if you place the `--spam` flag after specifying your variable arguments.

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('pos')
p.add_argument('foo')
p.add_argument('--spam', default=24, type=int, dest='spam')
p.add_argument('vars', nargs='*')

p.parse_args('1 2 8 9 --spam 8'.split())
```

EDIT: For what it's worth, it seems that changing the `*` to a `+` will also fix the error.

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('pos')
p.add_argument('foo')
p.add_argument('--spam', default=24, type=int, dest='spam')
p.add_argument('vars', nargs='+')

p.parse_args('1 2 --spam 8 8 9'.split())
```

Comment: Well yes I could do that, but that's not what I want. I'm building a command line tool, so I'm not the one who will write the arguments. I cannot force on the user a specific solution. The code I wrote should work and should be flexible. I really don't know why it fails.

Comment: True, but it's quite possible that `argparse` cannot handle this particular situation. It's also quite possible that the rules for argument parsing do not allow for the arguments to be positioned in this way. Anyway, I've amended my answer with another potential solution, FWIW.

Comment: You're right, eventually it turned up to be an argparse bug, as the other answer describes.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to have at least one optional argument then `p.add_argument('vars', nargs='+')` will work in your specific case