# argparser and sup parsers

Tags: python, argparse

When we use add_parser, the function builds and returns a Parser object, there is any way to do the same thing with an already built Parser object ?

I'd like to build from a class the parser corresponding to the object. This way from a main script I could call a class method that return the class parser and add it to a higher level parser to build the final command line.

How can I do this ?
thanks,
Jerome

Comment: Why not pass the parser returned by `add_parser` into the method that initializes it instead of creating it in that method?

Comment: Yes I thought about it but I found it less elegant, isn't it ?

Comment: @user1595929 Maybe you're, but i don't. I think it's an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear about what you need, but may be this outline of what happens when you create subparsers will help.

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [3]: sp=p.add_subparsers()

In [4]: sp
Out[4]: _SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='==SUPPRESS==', nargs='A...',
    const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=OrderedDict(), help=None,
    metavar=None)

In [5]: sp._parser_class
Out[5]: argparse.ArgumentParser
In [7]: spp=sp.add_parser('cmd')

In [8]: spp
Out[8]: ArgumentParser(prog='ipython cmd', usage=None, description=None,
    version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>,     
    conflict_handler='error',add_help=True)
```

`sp` is a positional `Action` that takes `choices` (the subparser names).  It has a `hidden` attribute `_parser_class` that is the class that it uses to create the new subparsers.

[Argparse: how to handle variable number of arguments (nargs='*')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165843/argparse-how-to-handle-variable-number-of-arguments-nargs/20167038#20167038) raises the possibility of changing that `_parser_class` to produce different behavior in the subparsers.  http://bugs.python.org/issue17204 is a related bug issue.

If the subparser just needs an extra method (or a customized version of an existing one), there are a couple of ways to do it:

- subclass `ArgumentParser` and use the subclass for the parser (works if the parser does not use the new method).
- use the above discussion to create a subparser with the new class
- add the new method to the subparser object itself.

Threads like [Python: changing methods and attributes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962962/python-changing-methods-and-attributes-at-runtime) discuss the ins and outs of changing the methods of an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can so it like this: Normally define the `ArgumentParser` you want to use, then pass it to your modules:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
some_module.add_arguments(parser)
```

and have an `add_arguments()` method in your modules/objects:

```
def add_arguments(parser):
    parser.add_argument(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I like to do it in my command line tool Python scripts.

I have a main class that represents the tool:

```
class MyToolCommandLineDriver(object):

    @classmethod
    def subcommand_map(cls):
        # create a mapping of subcommand names to classes
        return subcommand_map

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        subcommand_map = cls.subcommand_map()

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some Tool')
        parser.add_argument('--some_global_option', help='Some Help')

        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='Subcommands', dest='subcommand_name')
        for subcommand_name, subcommand_class in subcommand_map.items():
            subparser = subparsers.add_parser(subcommand_name, help=subcommand_class.__doc__)
            subcommand_class.configure_argument_parser(subparser)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyToolCommandLineDriver.run()
```

Each of those `subcommand_class` items derives from a common base class and gets a chance to configure its own parser:

```
class AbstractSubcommand(object):

    @classmethod
    def configure_argument_parser(cls, parser):
        pass

class SubcommandFooBar(AbstractSubcommand):

    @classmethod
    def configure_argument_parser(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument('some_argument', nargs='+', help='Some help')
```

You can see the full example here: https://github.com/liyanage/git-tools/blob/master/githelper/githelper.py

That is a subcommand-based tool I made. This setup lets each subcommand define its specific arguments, and it also results in useful usage messages for free, both at the top-level:

```
$ githelper.py -h
usage: githelper.py [-h] [--root_path ROOT_PATH] [--verbose]

    {status,reset-master-to-svn-branch,svn-conflicts,clone-externals,tree,svn-lineage,svn-diff,branch,each,svn-delete-resolve,svn-mergeinfo,svn-rebase,foo,checkout}
```

and for each subcommand:

```
$ githelper.py clone-externals -h
usage: githelper.py clone-externals [-h] svn_url checkout_directory

positional arguments:
  svn_url             The toplevel SVN repository to clone
  checkout_directory  The path to the sandbox directory to create
```