# command line arguments python changes

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, arguments

Is there a way to define command line arguments in Python, but the number of those argument changes?

For example I have this list:

arguments = [arg1, arg2, arg3]

My script would be invoked from another place like this:

python3 python_script.py arg1 arg2 arg3

But, the number of arguments could change:

python3 python_script.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5

So, is there a way to make sure that array is extendable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argparse: how to handle variable number of arguments (nargs='\*')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165843/argparse-how-to-handle-variable-number-of-arguments-nargs)

Comment: Luckily it's not an array but an extendable list.

Comment: @S4eed3sm thank you for your reply, that helped a lot, I read the comments on that page and managed to find the solution for setup. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The number of args is variable already. This is a property of your shell not of python. You can get the list with sys.argv.

```py
# run.py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

```sh
python3 run.py a b c d
>>> ['run.py', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Do you have a suggestion on how to use those arguments later in the script? I was thinking if something like this is possible: arguments = [arg1, arg2, [expect a list of arguments or one],  arg3]?

Comment: Are you trying to validate some property of the list ? Eg. There is more than 1 arg? Add that to your post if so.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the python script use the variable `len(sys.argv)` to figure out how many arguments are passed to the python script.

Create the `arguments` array based on the value from `len(sys.argv)` and then do the required operations on the array `arguments`

```
import sys
n = len(sys.argv)
arguments = []
for i in range(1,n):
    arguments.append(sys.argv[i])
```